# Método que chama thread para consultar um web service sempre retorna null

Tags: java, android

Quando vou chamar este método a seguir em outra classe ele está  retornando null. Porem já realizei o debug na linha **"return listNotas;"** e ela está sendo preenchida normalmente.

Código do método:

```
    ArrayList<Nota> listNotas = new ArrayList<>();

public ArrayList buscarNotas(String matricula, int etapa){

    try {
        SoapObject resposta = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


            resposta.addProperty("Matricula", matricula);
            resposta.addProperty("Etapa", etapa);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(resposta);

        HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        String resultado = envelope.getResponse().toString();

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(resultado);


        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++ ) {
            Nota nota = new Nota();
            JSONObject jsonObject =jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            nota.setDisciplina(jsonObject.getString("Materia"));
            nota.setNota(jsonObject.getString("VlrNota"));

            listNotas.add(i,nota);
        }
    }  catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
        soapFault.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   return listNotas;

}
```

Chamada do método em outra classe. Obs: onde está recebendo null

```
public List<Nota> baixarNotas (final String matricula, final int etapa){

    String msg = "Carregando";
    String titulo = "Aguarde";
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

       listaNotas= notaWS.buscarNotas(matricula,etapa);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }}).start();

        return listaNotas;
}
```

Comment: Olá, Alan. Por favor, comece ajustando a formatação, pois fica difícil entender o problema quando o código está difícil de ler. Provavelmente seu problema está na natureza assíncrona das threads. Você não pode simplesmente retornar um valor que será buscado em outra thread, pois você retornará algo não pronto muito antes da outra thread realmente executar e fazer o processo que você quer.

Comment: Olá, Pablo! Muito obrigado pela atenção e pela dica sobre a formatação. No caso do return, como faço para recebe-lo de forma correta? (sou iniciante em java).

Comment: Antes de mais nada, por que a thread?

Comment: Pois o método buscarNotas acessa um web service para preencher o list, por isso o executo em uma thread a parte.

Comment: Mesmo assim, não tem por que criar threads dessa forma em um código Android. O ideal seria você usar uma AsyncTask ou, melhor ainda, usar uma biblioteca pra fazer esse trabalho. Threads têm vários problemas no Android. Esse que você está enfrentando é só um deles.

Comment: Numa busca rápida, parece que uma boa para SOAP é essa: http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/index.html

Comment: Blz. Vou dar uma estudada sobre AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na thread. Como a execução da thread é assincrona, o método responde antes do  **listaNotas = notaWS.buscarNotas(matricula,etapa)** ser executado.

Olhe o código abaixo.

```
public List<Nota> baixarNotas (final String matricula, final int etapa){
    String msg = "Carregando";
    String titulo = "Aguarde";
    final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, titulo, msg);

    try {
        listaNotas= notaWS.buscarNotas(matricula,etapa);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    return listaNotas;
}
```

Caso você queira manter a thread terá que implementar um método de callback e remover o **return** do método **baixarNotas**